# Need help looping and testing Entities in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a new project using Entity Framework that is using Database First. This is because it looks at sql data that already exists on several different customers sites. The one issue we sometimes find is where there are slight discrepancies between the database our end and the database at a customer. For example we may have a field that is nullable and on some customers its set to not null which then causes an EF error at their end.  I don't know whey they are different as they existed before I got anywhere near them.

I have the following code already which loops through the dbsets but I can't seem to create a sql query that passes the dbset type to run a query against it to test if the model matches the database, can anyone help?

```
System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext ctx = ((System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.IObjectContextAdapter)db).ObjectContext;
        System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.MetadataWorkspace workspace = ctx.MetadataWorkspace;
        IEnumerable<System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.EntityType> tables = workspace.GetItems<System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.EntityType>(System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.DataSpace.SSpace);
        foreach (var table in tables)
        {
            var tableSchema = table.MetadataProperties["TableName"].Value.ToString();
            // Need something here to dynamically select all results
            // If could pass the Entity Type to db.Database.SqlQuery<type> problem would be solved                
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the built in method of entity framework

```
context.Database.CompatibleWithModel(true);
```

Or you could read the systables of the database.

**This code may not match your sql server!**

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, DOMAIN_NAME, NULLS, WIDTH FROM SYSTABLE LEFT JOIN SYSCOLUMN ON SYSTABLE.TABLE_ID = SYSCOLUMN.TABLE_ID LEFT JOIN SYSDOMAIN ON SYSCOLUMN.DOMAIN_ID = SYSDOMAIN.DOMAIN_ID WHERE SYSTABLE.TABLE_NAME = 'YourTableHere'
```

This query will return all columns of a table, the types and if the column is nullable. Then compare this query result against your model. You can use the metadata or you read the properties from the classes with `GetProperties`.

```
public class DbColumnTypes {
    public String TABLE_NAME { get; set; };
    public String COLUMN_NAME { get; set; };
    public String DOMAIN_NAME { get; set; };
    public Boolean ISNULLABLE { get; set; };
}    

List<DbColumnTypes> dbColumns; //Read that from your DB
PropertyInfo[] properties = type.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public).ToArray();
foreach(PropertyInfo item in properties)
{
    if(dbColumns.Any(x => x.COLUMN_NAME == item.Name) {
        //compare the Database types to the C# types (varchar with string, etc.)
        if(item.Property.PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Nullable<>)
        {
            //check if database column is nullable
        }
    }
}
```

You can wrap that code in a method an call it for every class you have in your ef model. With this you can check if your database matches your model.

To get all types in your model you could enumerate all types in a namespace:

```
var theList = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes().Where(t => t.Namespace == "your.name.space").ToList();
```

With this list you can go trough all classes and call the method above.

Comment: We are talking about hundreds of tables, I'm trying to avoid having to manually check all the columns myself.

Comment: Also because its database first and not code first I cannot use CompatibleWithModel

Comment: Because of this you could compare the query result programmatically against the class properties in your project.

Comment: You're missing the part I actually need which is to iterate the dbsets and dynamically pass the type to run the query for each one

Comment: I've updated my answer with some code to get all types in a namespace.